# Can I show that something has the same distribution with help of discrete probability function, only looking at probabilities?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I have a sequence of (discrete) random variables $X_{n,k}$ which are idd $\forall n,k \in \mathbb{N}$. There is nothing else that I know about their distribution. I know though, that $X_{n,k}$ are distributed like $X_{1,1}$. Can I then write, that
$p_{i}=\mathbb{P}(X_{n,k}=i)=\mathbb{P}(X_{1,1}=i) \forall n,k,i \in \mathbb{N}$. I doesn't seem right to me, however I need to show, that the probability that $X_{n,k}$ takes the value $i$ is the same as the probability if $X_{1,1}$ takes a value $i$.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean when you write that a random variable $Y$ is "distributed like" a random variable $Z$?   I would have though that you meant that they had the same distribution, no?

Comment: iid means they are independent and identically distributed. Identically distributed for some two random variables $X$, $Y$ (as an example) means $P(X\in A) = P(Y\in A)$ for any Borel measurable $A$. Here $A = \{i\}$.

Comment: @lulu, yes, I mean they have the same distribution

Comment: Well, what does "having the same distribution" mean to you?

Comment: @Jakobian, alright, this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @lulu I would rather then take a look at distribution function, so not only comparing every single point. At the same, it is logical, that if random variables  have the same distribtuion, so they are taking the same values with the same probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose "idd" should be "iid"? In this case this is true. If $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed (they do not need even to be independent for that!), then $\mathbb P(X=x)=\mathbb P(Y=x)$.

This can be easily seen: $\mathbb P(X=x)= \lim _{y\to x,y<x} F_X(x)-F_X(y)$ (this follows directly from measures being continuous from above). So $\mathbb P(X=x)$ (and even $\mathbb P^X$) is directly given by $F_X=F_Y$. Thus

$$ \mathbb P(X=x)= \lim _{y\to x,y<x} F_X(x)-F_X(y) = \lim _{y\to x,y<x} F_Y(x)-F_Y(y) = P(Y=x) $$

Comment: Edited the answer because I had $\mathbb P(X=x)=\mathbb P(Y=y)$ in the first line, which should of course read $\mathbb P(X=x)=\mathbb P(Y=x)$.